# Bash script - for loop and if-else

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, hdfs

I am new to Bash scripting and despite multiple attempts to refactor the logic structure shown in pseudocode below I cant get this to work.  How do I piece the if/else logic together with a for loop?

**Pseudocode**:
 I have a command that checks if any subfolders exist in a directory of the HDFS filesystem.  Lets call this command_A.

```
If subfolders do NOT exist {
    proceed with remaining execution of script
}
Else {
    sleep for 30 minutes and run command_A again to see if the subfolders have been removed.  Note:  This sleep and re-check cycle should repeat up to 4 times and if subfolders are never removed the script is killed with exit 1
}
```

Sample of What I Have Tried is Below.  I can't figure out how I am supposed to use the || in conjunction with the else statement.

**Using these structures**:

```
1. for i in {1..4}; do command_A && break || sleep 1800; done
2. if command_A ; then echo "Command succeeded" else echo "Command failed" fi
```

**Test Example**:

```
for i in {1..4};
  do
     if hdfs dfs -test -e $mypath/*
       echo "Folder is empty" && break
else
     ???
```

***Update showing working solution***:

```
for i in {1..4};
  do
   if hdfs dfs -test -e $mypath/*;
     then
       if [ $i -eq 4 ]
        then
          echo "script exiting now with code 1"
       else
          echo "Folder is full"
          sleep 10
       fi
   else
    echo "Folder is empty"
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Why do you need `for i in {1..4};` for? You are not using `i` anywhere

Comment: @Inian I need to repeat the cycle of checking that the folders have been removed up to a total of 4 times within a 2 hour period.  If they are never removed, then I would exit the script as I dont want it to run indefinitely.

Comment: So just to understand what is not working here? Or what are you missing?

Comment: @HendPro12 not clear to me exactly what you try to do. you want to run a loop of maximum of 4 cycles and in the loop to run a command and test its result, and exit the loop if the result is not empty, otherwise sleep 30 mins and run the command again (until the loop exits by itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is the working complete code for this particular question, I'll keep the original slightly more generic code below for future reference since it is less complex (less nested if/else) for others searching for similar problems.

```
for i in {1..4};
  do
   if hdfs dfs -test -e $mypath/*;
     then
       if [ $i -eq 4 ]
        then
          echo "script exiting now with code 1"
       else
          echo "Folder is full"
          sleep 10
       fi
   else
    echo "Folder is empty"
    break
  fi
done
```

---

I think something like this will work, which is pretty much what you have.  You just have to put what you're checking for in the if statement and this code should work for you.

```
for i in {1..4}
do
   if [ <check for subdirs> ]
   then 
       echo "Folder is empty!" 
       break
   else
       sleep 1800
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! With a small swap of the content in the then and else blocks this is working.  Ive provided an update above to reflect the change.  If you want to update your response to match.  Ill mark it as the answer.  I incorrectly thought the || operator was required as part of the for loop and couldnt comprehend how that was suppposed to work in parallel with if/else.

Comment: Glad it helped.  You might have been over-thinking it (if I only had a dollar for every time I came up with a more complex than needed solution...) or sometimes switching between paradigms has weird side effects where we want to combine everything together lol.  I've updated the answer with your working code and left the slightly simplified version for anyone else stumbling upon this that might not need to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
sleep_count=0
max_attempts=4
for ((i=0; i < $max_attempts; i++)); do
  if hdfs dfs -test -e $mypath/*; then
     echo "No subfolders!"
     break
  else
     # subfolders exist; wait for a while and see if they go away
     ((sleep_count++))
     sleep 1800
  fi
done

if [[ $sleep_count == $max_attempts ]]; then
  # waited too long for subfolders to go away
  exit 1
fi

# probably repeat the above steps again?
```

Comment: Ive tested the command above successfully as a standalone command in the terminal.  What I cant figure out if the logic structure to repeat the check 3 or 4 more times if the check shows that folders exist on the first execution of the command.

Comment: @Inian The bash shell is running the script from the local OS and calling an hdfs filesystem command.  Not sure if this is what you are asking...but its a common use case to wrap hdfs commands inside of bash shell scripts